# Guide for multiple function for 1 button of MSP430F427 microcontroller

Tags: button, timer, embedded, msp430

I have 2 buttons, and each button has multiple function. They are pulled-up externally. I am using external oscillator 32kHz.

Button A (P1.2)

functions of button A:

1. a press on Button A would make the device be on
2. a hold for 5 seconds will turn off the device
3. a press on Button A (while on counting operation) would reset the counter

Button B (P1.3)
functions of button B:

1. a press on Button B will light LED (P1.1) and LED will turn off after 30 seconds.
2. a hold for 5 seconds will change its unit count (inches on first hold, cm in the next hold)

for now I have tried the button B as it is more easy for me for it does not involve LPMx/sleep mode.

```
volatile uint16_t ctr1 = 0;
volatile uint16_t ctr2 = 0; 
volatile uint16_t ctr3 = 0;    //counter for LED ON

void Init_Timer_A (void) 
{ 
// Timer_A0 Configuration 
TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;             // Enable Timer_A interrupt 
TA0CCR0 = 33;                // Set the Timer_A count limit 1ms intervals 
TA0CTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1;    // ACLK from watch crystal 32.768 kHz, Up Mode
}

pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A (void) 
{ 
if (counter1_enable_flag) 
    { 
    if (ctr1 <= 5000) 
    { 
        ctr1++; 
        if (ctr1 >= 100) 
        { 
            ctr3++; 
            if (ctr3 <= 4000) 
            { 
                P1OUT |= BIT1; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                P1OUT &= ~(BIT1); 
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        P1OUT |= BIT1;
        ctr1 = 0;
    }

    }
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    initialize(); 
    GPIO_init(); 
    Init_Timer_A();

    __enable_interrupt();

    while (1)
    {
        if ((P1IN & BIT2) == 0)    // 1-0 | Button1 (P1.2) is pressed
        {
        counter1_enable_flag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to make the LED light up for 30 seconds for a press of button, and when I hold the button for 5 seconds (it should do a certain function) but to make it simple I just want it first to make the LED stay on/high.

if (ctr3 <= 4000) in this line of code, I can only light up the LED for 4 seconds, when I make it 5000, it stays on and doesn't turn off.

Moreover, if I include the else statement, I can see that it LED blink every 5 seconds. Also, if I push the button it does not light up for 4 seconds anymore. It just blink every 5 seconds.

If I exclude the else statement, the first push of button lights up the LED for 4 seconds and it doesn't blink every 5 seconds, however, it does not light up if I pushed the button it the next time.

Comment: I don't see any code that would ever clear `counter1_enable_flag` or reset `ctr3`.

Comment: You should create a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You have certain events (button pressed, button released, timer). For each combination of event and previous state, write out what the desired action and new state should be. Take care to list all combinations, even those without an action, to ensure that you do not forget one. Then you have a large list of conditions; just implement them in C. Trying to optimize/simplify the logic increases the risk of introducing logic errors.